# I want to fill background image even using scroll

Tags: html, css

I try to make div tag dynamically  but when I make 13th div then bottom of web makes empty space(white color). So I want to fix this situation

here is css code:

```
.bg-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,rgba(0, 47, 75, 0.60),rgba(220,66, 37, 0.60)), url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/439853/pexels-photo-439853.jpeg') center center / cover;
}
```

Comment: Try min-height:100vh;

Comment: Sure, Let me know if it works

Comment: @ThanveerShah
Thank you so much. It works very well.

Comment: Then can I post this answer in the answer section so you can accept it? that would help me

Comment: Sure. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fill up the entire height of the device

`min-height:100vh`;